# Security Error while installing phing using pear

Tags: pear, phing

I am installing phing using instructions [here](http://pear.phing.info/)
I get the following error. I have pear version 1.9.3

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# pear install phing/phing
SECURITY ERROR: package in channel "pear.phing.info" retrieved another channel's name for download! ("pear.php.net")
install failed
```

[This ticket](http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/244) shows the error was reported but they could not reproduce it!

Any workaround suggested?

OS: CentOS

Comment: I found no other way but to resort to non-PEAR install. See [this](http://katsande.com/phing-build-system-for-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download it with

```
$ pear download pear.phing.info/phing
```

- you will have a .tgz file now. Look inside and see if the package.xml really contains a `<channel>pear.php.net</channel>` line. If this is really so, please report back.

Otherwise, just install the downloaded file with

```
$ pear install Phing-1.2.3.tgz
```

Answer (score 2):

I know your question is quite old, but perhaps it will help someone else.

I would have tried `pear clear-cache`. I already have had some Security errors which disappeared after having cleaning the cache